# How would one solve for a process where a stochastic random variable is divided by a deterministic random variable?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I'm currently working on a problem where I am trying to model a stochastic process where a stochastic random variable is divided by a deterministic random variable following a normal distribution. Its been a while wince I had a look at stochastic calc so apologies in advance if my math is a bit rusty!

Consider a simple stochastic process with no drift that satisfies the following SDE

*Y(t) = X(t)*

*dX(t)* = $\sigma$*dB(t)* where *B(t)* is Brownian motion and *B(t)* ~ *N($0$,t)*.

Solving such a process would give me *Y(t) = Y$_0$ + $\sigma$B(t)*

I'm currently trying to find out what the resultant stochastic process would be if *Y(t) = $\frac{X(t)}{Z}$* where Z is a Normal distribution with mean $\mu_z$ and variance $\sigma_z^2$ i.e *Z* ~ *N($\mu_z$,$\sigma_z^2$)*.

How would one apply Ito's lemma in such a case?

Comment: You already know that $X(t) = X(0) + \sigma B(t)$ so $Y(t) = \frac{X(0)}{Z} + \frac{\sigma}{Z} B(t)$.

Comment: Perfect! That makes total sense! Cheers :)